# github desktop not showing folders

Tags: github

I made changes on the folder called "`client/`" but they are not shown in GitHub Desktop, thus I can push it to my repository:

[image: changes]

Inside there is a `.gitignore` file, and I have tried deleting it but even so the "`client/`" folder did not appear.

[image: client]

Here is the content in gitignore file.

```
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*
```

How can I see changes in `client/`?

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check if any `.gitignore` rule applies to your change (therefore ignoring said change) with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- client/my/changed/file
```

If it does return anything, any modification to that file would be ignored.

Second, check if client is a *nested* Git repository (meaning, with a `client/.git` subfolder): that would also explain why a change in that nested repository is not shown when GitHub Desktop display the parent repository.

The [OP Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15195073/henry) mentions in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612274/github-desktop-not-showing-folders/66614568?noredirect=1#comment117769923_66614568):

> ```sh
> git check-ignore -v client/node_modules`  
> fatal: Pathspec 'client/node_modules' is in submodule 'client' , so did other folders
> ```

That means it is a [`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) which is declared in the parent repository, in the `.gitmodules`.

The client folder, therefore, is supposed to be empty on the GitHub parent repository: it is a gitlink, a special entry in the index, referencing the tree SHA of that submodule repository.

Comment: after running "git status --ignored",  othing to commit, working tree clean. Client folder is uploaded, but empty folder.

Comment: @Henry What does the `git check-ignore -v` command returns (using as a parameter any file in the `client/` folder)?

Comment: at first, it returned ??client. Thus, i cleaned (git rm cached), added it, commit, and finally push it to my repository. But it ended up be a empty folder.

Comment: @Henry So now `git check-ignore -v ` returns nothing? (still using  as arameter any file in the `client/` folder)

Comment: now it returns "nothing to commit, working tree clean". but the "client" folder is still empty.

Comment: @Henry A `git check-ignore` would not return that. A `git status` would.

Comment: Youre right. I ran git check-ignore -v client/ this time but it returned nothing.

Comment: @Henry I meant running `git check-ignore -v -- client/my/changed/file`, using a file which is in the `client/` folder.

Comment: git check-ignore -v client/node_modules                                            
 fatal: Pathspec 'client/node_modules' is in submodule 'client' ,                           so did other folders.

Comment: @Henry OK so that is why client is empty! It is declared as a submodule, in a .gitmodules. I will update the answer.